# ClassCastException when trying to set margins on List item

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to create a method that can displace a list element horizontally given a distance. The list element is a RelativeLayout, so I do the following:

```
    // cast View to RelativeLayout 
    RelativeLayout listLayout = (RelativeLayout) listElement;
    // Get layout params
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) listLayout.getLayoutParams();
    //set the margins
    layoutParams.setMargins(distance,0,0,0);
    // ??
    listLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    // Profit!!!
```

I checked in the debugger, and the list item is a RelativeLayout, even before I cast it (just to make sure). However I get the following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

I have tried lots of variations on this, and they all stop with a cast error. But I cannot figure out why, as a RelativeLayout is being used, so I should be able to call that method and get back a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams object.

Answer (score 0):

Your listLayout is inside of other view that is not a RelativeLayout, so the LayoutParams is not a RelativeLayout.LayoutParam... try use the [ViewGroup.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) intead, like below:

```
// Get layout params
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = listLayout.getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: That works, except that the setMargins method is gone. Which sort of defeats the purpose. Does this mean that I can only progammatically set margins on a top-level element?

Comment: @TomMacdonald I don't know a way to do it programmatically but probably have one way.
Add your layout inside a Relativelayout is a way, but probably have a better way.

Comment: @TomMacdonald and the why you don't have the setMargins is because that method is declared in this class `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`  this class extends the ViewGroup.LayoutParams, and relativelayout.LayoutParams extends the ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams class.